# Is it possible to circumvent (ignore) routing table without root permissions?

Tags: network, linux, penetration-test, network-scanners

The local host is configured to send all non-local traffic to a restrictive firewall VM configured in the routing table (`route`).

Preliminary scanning shows that other routers are available on the local network that may not be as restrictive as the firewall VM.

Is it possible to send traffic, destined for the Internet, without it being routed through the firewall VM as a normal user?